# TYPO3 Fluid: Map m:n values from multiple select form to model

Tags: typo3, multi-select, fluid, extbase

I have a m:n relation in my domain model:

- *inquiry* is the aggregate root in my domain model
- several *investigators* can be assigned to each inquiry.

In the *inquiry* model this is defined:

```
/**
 * @var Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage<Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Investigator>
 */
protected $investigator;
```

The *investigator* domain model is mapped to the fe_user table of TYPO3, which is noted properly in the configuration (`ext_typoscript_setup.txt`):

```
config.tx_extbase{
    persistence{
        classes{
            Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Investigator {
                mapping {
                    recordType = Tx_Extbase_Domain_Model_FrontendUser
                    tableName = fe_users
                }
            }
        }
```

This works fine, I can display and edit inquiry records in the backend and frontend. However, when I want to change the investigators assigned to one inquiry (from edit action), I get an exception after submitting my form:

```
#1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "investigator":
No converter found which can be used to convert from "array" to
"Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage"
```

The multiselect-box that I use for this is created like that:

```
<f:form.select multiple="true" size="10" property="investigator" 
value="{inquiry.investigator}" options="{allInvestigators}" 
optionLabelField="name" />
```

Which is rendered like this:

```
<select name="tx_myext_inquiry[inquiry][investigator][]" size="10" multiple="true">
    <option value="362">John Doe</option>
    <option value="590">Jane Doe</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="361">Steve Miller</option>
    <option value="720">James Brown</option>
    <option value="726">Janis Joplin</option>
</select>
```

`{allInvestigators}` is an array with all users from the group "investigators".
The values already stored are marked with "selected", which proves that some of my code is correct ;).

I tried fiddling around with the type converter  (`Tx_Extbase_Property_TypeConverter_PersistentObjectConverter` [Dok](http://goo.gl/S4FDS)) in the InquiryController to cast my array to an object, but it to no avail. The field *investigator* is passed as an array to the update action, which triggers the exception.

I spend five hours on this now, need to move on.

- **How can I get rid of this error message?**
- **Is converting the array to an object the right approach at all?**

(Any questions for more details will be answered ASAP)

---

**Edit:**
Environment: TYPO3 version 6.1.1, Fluid 6.1.0, Extbase 6.1.0

Comment: @froemken added a link to a test extension: "Here is my test extension: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvnxzr75xvxmvyq/sfinvestigator_0.0.1.zip Please tell me what I have done wrong or missunderstood." Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit in the model definition in `Classes/Domain/Model/Inquiry.php`

```
/**
 * @var Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage<Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Investigator>
 */
protected $investigator;
```

I changed (part of) the @var annotation to *name space* style:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_Investigator>
 */
protected $investigator;
```

Now the update process works. I guess in our project we need to standardize the model to name spaces.
If this is a bug, I will file it at forge.typo3.org.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a known problem in the 6.* branches of TYPO3.

See http://forge.typo3.org/issues/54289 there is currently a patch pending to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it with TYPO3 6.1 and TYPO3 6.2-dev from GIT and can't reproduce this problem. So it would be nice if you can give up some environment informations. Please start with your current TYPO3-Version.

Comment: This ought to be a comment, not a question

Comment: Correction: *not an answer ;).

Comment: It's my first time here and I don't know everything. I see a share and edit link, but I don't see how to add a comment or question regarding this thread. So the nearest option was to add an answer.

Comment: Thanks a million, froemken. The principle here is: Only answer a question if you can provide a solution to the problem. To envolve in the discussion, use the "comment" link below each question/answer. It's quite useful, because the best/correct solution is always shown on top, and the discussion doesn't lose focus.